# how to move specific files based on their extensions

Tags: command-line

I want a command that allows to select specific files based on their extensions to move them to another directory.

Comment: In any algorithm that you could use, you need to have in mind the scope of the path of the search. Because in a Linux system you could have a  file called `system.a.backup`. Is just a mention..

Comment: You'll need to give us more details.  What extension, whether you're trying to recursively move items, etc. are all relevant information here.

Comment: I'm trying to move .pdf files only from a directory to another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this easily from one directory with:

```
mv /path/to/original/directory/*.pdf /path/to/new/directory
```

The command for a recursive move can be a little more complex. This should do the trick though:

```
find /original/directory/ | grep '\.pdf' | xargs -I {} mv {} /path/to/new/directory/
```

With the second command `/original/directory` will be search recursively for `.pdf` files.

Comment: Are you sure that the second command works? Because I can't make it work.

Comment: @Lucio extra `-0` on `xargs` option was definitely the problem. I removed it so it should work now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I guess this will also work: `find /original/directory/ -iname *.pdf -exec mv {} /path/to/new/directory/ \;`

Answer (score 3):

why not 
`cp /path/to/dir/where/pdf/are/*.pdf /path/to/where/ever`

Comment: Because that copies the file, it does not move it?

Answer (score 1):

Another method using recursive globs (available in zsh and bash): `mv /path/to/original/directory/**/*.pdf /path/to/new/directory/`

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
for file in { ls *. pdf} 
do
mv "$file" /destination /here 
done
```

So here before doing this you must change into your directory where you have files.

Comment: Doing from mobile. Could someone put it in the format plz

Comment: Plus the actual script, you can add another one with `-R` as a parameter in the `ls` command, adding the recursive feature. Anyway, your script is the cleanest and more easy to understand.